# Error when updating data in codeigniter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this problem when updating my product table.
It shows the error message but I can't determine where are the problems because its customize message.
I just need to update product when user made changes and notify if user doesn't make changes.

product_update_view.php

```
<div class="col-sm-10" id="main" style="padding: 20px;">
    <?php
    echo form_open("item/item_update/$item->prod_id");
    echo form_fieldset('<h3 class="text-info">Update Item</h3>');
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_code" value="<?php echo $item->prod_code ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_name" value="<?php echo $item->prod_desc ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_category" value="<?php echo $item->category_name ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_brand" value="<?php echo $item->brand_name ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_sizes" value="<?php echo $item->size ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_price" value="<?php echo $item->original_price ?>">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for='prod_code'>Product Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="up_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->prod_code; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for='prod_name'>Product Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name=up_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->prod_desc; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for='up_brand'>Brand:</label>
        <select name="up_brand" class="form-control">
            <option value="Select Brand" selected="selected">Select Brand</option>


            <?php foreach($brand as $br): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $br->brand_id; ?>" <?php
                if($br->brand_id == $item->brand_id)
                {
                    echo "selected='selected'";
                }
                ?>><?php echo $br->brand_name ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>      

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="up_category" id="category">
            <option value="Select Brand"> Select Category</option>
            <?php foreach($category as $cat): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cat->category_id; ?>" <?php
                        if($cat->category_id == $item->category_id)
                        {
                            echo "selected='selected'";
                        }
                        ?>><?php echo $cat->category_name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sizes">Size:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="up_sizes" id="sizes" disabled="disabled">

                    <?php foreach($sizes as $sz): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $sz->size_id; ?>" <?php
                    if($sz->size_id == $item->size_id)
                    {
                        echo "selected='selected'";
                    }
                    ?>><?php echo $sz->size; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for='prod_price'>Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="up_price" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->original_price; ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_account" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Product" >
    </div>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>dropdown/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>dropdown/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#category').on('click', function () {
            var category_id = $(this).val();
            if (category_id === '')
            {
                $('#sizes').prop('disabled', true);
            } else
            {
                $('#sizes').prop('disabled', false);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/get_sizes",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'category_id': category_id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#sizes').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error occur...!!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

controller

```
public function item_update($id)
{
    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('up_code', 'Product Code', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('up_name', 'Product Description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('up_price', 'Price', 'required');

    $cur_name = $this->input->post('cur_name');
    $cur_code = $this->input->post('cur_code');
    $cur_category = $this->input->post('cur_category');
    $cur_price = $this->input->post('cur_price');
    $cur_brand = $this->input->post('cur_brand');
    $cur_sizes = $this->input->post('cur_sizes');
    $up_name = $this->input->post('up_name');
    $up_category = $this->input->post('up_category');
    $up_code = $this->input->post('up_code');
    $up_price = $this->input->post('up_price');
    $up_sizes = $this->input->post('up_sizes');
    $up_brand = $this->input->post('up_brand');
    if($cur_code === $up_code && $cur_name === $up_name && $cur_brand === $up_brand && $cur_category === $up_category && $cur_sizes === $up_sizes && $cur_price === $up_price)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('successMessage', '<div class="alert alert-info">No Changes</div>');
        redirect(base_url('home'));
    }
    else
    {
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('errorMessage',
              '<div class="alert alert-danger">Opss Something Went Wrong Updating The Item. Please Try Again.</div>');
            redirect(base_url('home'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('item_model');
            $update = $this->item_model->update_item($id, $up_code, $up_name, $up_brand, $up_category, $up_size,
              $up_price);

            if($update)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('successMessage',
                  '<div class="alert alert-success">Item Updated</div>');
                redirect(base_url('home'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my model

```
public function update_item($id, $up_code, $up_name, $up_brand, $up_category,
  $up_sizes, $up_price)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array(
      'prod_code' => "$up_code",
      'prod_desc' => "$up_name",
      'brand_id' => "$up_brand",
      'category_id' => "$up_category",
      'size_id' => "$up_sizes",
      'original_price' => "$up_price",
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('products', $data);
}
```

It only shows the message **"Opss Something Went Wrong Updating The Item. Please Try Again"**

Comment: did you check your log?

Comment: I can see $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE is giving an error so double check required fields and i seen typo in <input type="text" name=up_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->prod_desc; ?>">

Comment: I huge part of being a successful developer is learning how to debug your issues, but another is reading documentation, and CodeIgniter very clearly shows how to use the form validation library. Please go read that section, and  you'll see that you could be displaying the validation errors instead of a generic "oops" message.